# Migration issue while using DMS . Incorrect junk data for empty columns

Tags: oracle, database-migration, aws-dms

While migrating from MySQL to ORAcle using AWS DMS servcie, In the source side(MySQL DB instance), some huge column (mediumtext) values are empty for 75% of rows in a table. Whereas in the target (Oracle ), its migrated with some other value (Not Junk values) . For me it looks like the column values are copied incorrectly between rows.

Wherever there is empty values in the source side columns, it copied some other data. Around 75% of table data for some of the clob columns with empty values in source side, are incorrectly mapped with some other data in the oracle side. We used FULL LOB mode and 10000Kb as chunk size.

Answer (score 0):

Some questions or requests - 
1. Could you share the table DDL from source and target?
2. Are you sure there is no workload running on the target that could change values in the table outside the DMS process? 
3. Full LOB mode migrates LOBs in chunks. Why are we specifying such a high LOB chunk size? Also, do we not know the max LOB size to use limited LOB mode. 
4. Could you paste the task ARN here? I work for AWS DMS and can look to see what is going on? Once I find the root cause, I will also make sure I post an analysis here for all stackoverflow users.

Let me know.